# Update wsdl definition and requests programmatically and keep parameters/properties in SoapUI

Tags: soap, groovy, wsdl, soapui

We have a lot of wsdls and it's pretty annoying to update/refactor/update definitions and requests in my SoapUI project so I started to work a bit on groovy script for this. Curreny it look like this:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*
import com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Interface
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import TestHelper.Wsdl.*

import static com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.iface.UpdateInterfaceAction.recreateRequests
import static com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.iface.UpdateInterfaceAction.recreateTestRequests

class UpdateWsdls {

    WsdlProjectPro wsdlProject
    Logger log

    public UpdateWsdls(Logger log, String projectFileName) {
           this.log = log
        this.wsdlProject = new WsdlProjectPro(projectFileName)
    }

    void updateInterfaceDefinitions(List<WsdlInfo> wsdlInfos) {
           if(!wsdlProject.isOpen()) {
            log.warn "Failed to open project"
            return
           }
        wsdlInfos.each { wsdlInfo ->
            def interfaceNames = getBindingNames(wsdlInfo.path)
            interfaceNames.each {
                updateInterfaceDefinition(it, wsdlInfo)
            }

        }        
    }

    void updateInterfaceDefinition(String interfaceName, WsdlInfo wsdlInfo) {        
        List<Interface> interfacesList = wsdlProject.interfaceList
        interfacesList.each { Interface anInterface ->
            if (anInterface instanceof WsdlInterface && interfaceName.equals(anInterface.name)) {
                WsdlInterface wsdlInterface = (WsdlInterface) anInterface
                def currentVersion = -1
                def text = wsdlInterface.getBindingName().toString().split('}');
                if(text.size() > 0) {
                    currentVersion = WsdlHelper.getVersionNumber(text[0])
                }
                if(currentVersion < wsdlInfo.version) {
                    log.info "Updating ${interfaceName}, ${currentVersion} -> ${wsdlInfo.version}"
                    wsdlInterface.updateDefinition(wsdlInfo.path, false)
                    updateRequests(wsdlInterface)
                } else {
                    log.info "${interfaceName} already up-to-date with version ${currentVersion}"
                }
            }            
        }
    }

    void updateRequestDo(WsdlInterface wsdlInterface) {
            try {
            recreateRequests(wsdlInterface,false,false,true,false)
            } 
            catch(Exception ex) {
                log.warn "Failed to update request ${wsdlInterface.getBindingName()}"
            }
            try {
                recreateTestRequests(wsdlInterface,false,false,true,false)
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                log.warn "Failed to update test request ${wsdlInterface.getBindingName()}"
            }     
    }

    void saveWsdlProject() {
        wsdlProject.save()
        wsdlProject.release()
    }

    def getBindingNames(String wsdlFile) {
        def definitions = new XmlParser().parse(new File(wsdlFile))
        return definitions.getByName('*:binding').@name
    }

}


def projectPath = ".." 
//Path to directory with the latest wsdls
def wsdlPathRoot = ".."

def w = new WsdlHelper(log) 
//Get info (name, path, verison number) of the latest wsdls
def wsdlInfos = w.getLatestWsdlInfo(wsdlPathRoot) 

UpdateWsdls updateWsdl = new UpdateWsdls(log, projectPath)
log.info "Updating definitions"
updateWsdl.updateInterfaceDefinitions(wsdlInfos)
log.info "Saving project"
updateWsdl.saveWsdlProject()
log.info "Restart SoapUI for changes to take effect"
```

In summary it do this:

1. Walk trough the directory at wsdlPathRoot for all wsdls and pick out those with the latest version.
2. Loop through our current interfaces and check if we have the latest version.
3. If not, update it's definition with the new path and recreate requests and test requests.

This works fine so far, the problem is that all my data/properties in all my requests/tests are gone. This is a pretty big deal as many of our requests take 10+ parameters and it would take a long time to insert them manually again.

I know soapui pro have a function that is called "refactor definition" and it manage to put everything back after an update. Is it possible to use/call on this programmatically?

Comment: You only want to update the wsdls not the requests?

Comment: The script was written to update the definitions and test requests. I am afraid that is possible like that, because one do not aware what changes going to come in the updated wsdls, hence updating them in the first place.

Comment: Well thats sad then. Is it possible to call on the refactor dialog then?